# Can you use the new Facebook comment system inside a Facebook app iframe?

Tags: facebook

Can this be done without triggering a recursive freak phenomena that will be the death of facebook itself?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, just use the URL of the app as the data-href="" attribute.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/YOURPAGE?sk=app_YOURAPPID" data-colorscheme="light" data-num-posts="20" data-width="510"></div>
```